# why we pass same value in first 2 argument of execlp()

Tags: c, exec

Following is the function declaration:

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

and following is argument discription:

```
file: The executable that has to be executed by  the new process. This executable is searched for in the path specified by the environmental variable PATH. 

*arg,...: list of arguments terminated by a NULL argument.
```

then why we call function like this:

```
execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
```

won't it become "ls -ls" , what it mean?

Comment: With that it will be `ls` not `ls -ls` .

Comment: yes you are correct , but I am just not able to relate it whatever written in man page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the binary to load for execution. The second is the name of the process (like e.g. displayed in the output of `ps`). It's quite common they are the same, but it is not necessary.

As a consequence, in the binary that is executed by `exec*()`, the name you give the process is available as `argv[0]`.

Comment: can you give any example where process name is different from binary name .... other than busybox... because I am not familiar with busybox,

Comment: if I give execlp("ls", "pankaj", NULL); , will it work , and is it like "process name will be pankaj here"?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha yes. Try with something that runs a bit longer than `ls` and verify with `ps` :)

Comment: yes I verified , I gave execlp("ping","myping1","135.250.134.23",NULL); in a program and output of ps command is showing "myping1 135.250.134.23", so 2nd argument is name of the process , so it mean we can give different name to process from binary using 2nd argument of function :) I always thought , process name will be always same to binary name , but i was wrong :)

Comment: @pankajkushwaha it's just convention, probably because it helps the user to identify a process, and shells will follow it. But there are (rare) situations where it's useful to give a different process name.

Comment: I'm confused: does process have the notion of "name"? I thought process is identified by PID

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) document about execlp (Bold fonts added by me)

> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program. **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed**. The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Comment: Can filename be different from file being executed?

Answer (score 3):

No, the first argument is the name the executable would be called. For example in many UNIX systems you will have symbolic links to a single executable and the executable can then determine how it was called. One example is [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands), which is a single binary but it includes dozens and dozens of commands worth of functionality.

Usually though the name is the same as the executable file and most executables don't care what the name is.

So for example in the BusyBox case if you would call `execlp("/path/to/busybox", "ls", NULL);` it would behave as the command `ls` should and if you would call `execlp("/path/to/busybox", "ps", NULL);` it would behave like `ps` command. The same with symlinks would just be `execlp("/path/to/ps", "ps", NULL);`

Comment: In this scenario, using symlinks, they would still be the same. But you could call busybox programatically (without symlinks) to perform `ls` with `execlp("busybox", "ls", NULL);`

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm not sure I follow you. I mean if you have a symlink called `ls` pointing to a program called `foo` you will receive *ls* as argv[0] and not *foo*. You mean that when `execlp`ing you would write the same values for both? That is true. Just explaining why they would be different.

Comment: I mean that in this case, the shell would still place `ls` in the first argument of the `exec*()` family of functions as well as in the first place of the argument list.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: So you mean  if you have a symlink called ls pointing to a program called foo , you have to call function like execlp("foo", "ls", NULL);?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha No, as Felix mentioned, you will have both as `ls` in that case. But you can create the same effect as having a symlink called *ls* by calling it that way.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I am sorry if its silly but for execlp("/path/to/busybox", "ls", NULL);, resulted as "/path/to/busybox ls" , which is ok , because we run busybox like "/bin/busybox ls" , but for execlp("/path/to/ps", "ps", NULL); why it not resulted as /path/to/ps ps?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha It doesn't equal to `busybox ls`, it is just that busybox happens to have two ways of determining what to do: if the argv[0] == "busybox", then it checks argv[1]. Otherwise it will check argv[0] for the command. And using `execlp("busybox", "ps", NULL);` will set argv[0] to *ps* and it will know what to do.

Comment: Now I understood, I gave execlp("ping","myping1","135.250.134.23",NULL); in a program and output of ps command is showing "myping1 135.250.134.23", so 2nd argument is name of the process.